# Keysight Waveform Building Software

Tags: waveform, function-generator

I want to create a waveform for the agilent 33220a waveform generator. It is a 40us arbitrary wave that I have designed in the keysight waveform builder pro via the Benchvue software, however I want it to then wait 1 second at 0 V DC (or just off) before the same wave is pulsed. There are not enough sampling points available to do this in the same .wvf file, due to the high sampling rate needed for the 40us waveform.

Is there a way to do this with the 33220a, for example telling it to not send any signal for 1 second without requiring any samples, or by using a high sample rate for the first 40us and then a much lower rate for the 1 second period?

Comment: Can you use it in some form of single shot mode then use a 1 second pule to repeat the waveform?

Comment: Hi @Andyaka, I looked into that and you can use the burst mode with the arbitrary waveform to trigger it only once per second, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

If the signal is continuous (repetition mode), you can use the ARBITRARY function and a period of 40μs, with the mode BURST (burst menu), 1 cycle, and a period of 1 sec and TRIG on INT.
In this case you will have your 40usec signal followed by a 0V level of 1sec. Important, the first point of your signal of 40μs must be 0 to be able to have 0V on one second.

In the case of a pulsed signal, it will be necessary to use the TRIG EXT. However you will have to give this signal 1 second delay. At startup, you will have 1 sec at 0V followed by your signal of 40μs then stop.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to do this with the 33220a, for example telling it to
>   not send any signal for 1 second without requiring any samples

Can you use it in some form of single shot mode then use a 1 second pule to repeat the waveform?

> Hi @Andyaka, I looked into that and you can use the burst mode with
>   the arbitrary waveform to trigger it only once per second, thanks for
>   the advice!